# Ember.js Dynamic Model Properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember.js (and Ember Data) allows me to specify properties of a model, such as `id`, `label` and `description`. But I allow my users to add their own properties to any model, which are obviously impossible for me to know about. Is there any way I can dynamically add properties to a model at runtime? (And more importantly, will Ember.js recognize changes on those properties and save them?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ember defines object properties via `Ember.defineProperty`. The signature is `Ember.defineProperty(object, propertyName, function)`. For instance to define a `lorem` property backed by `_lorem`, you can use

```
Ember.defineProperty(this, 'lorem', 
  Ember.computed(function (key, value) {
    if (value) {
      this.set('_lorem', value);
      return value;
    } else {
      return this.get('_lorem');
    }
  }  
));
```

You can call this method based in a user input handler when the `propertyName` is dynamic.
This sort of thing is best suited for extending the Meta object system. Caution is advised, especially with user input!