# Ember.js dynamic model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm looking into building an application with Ember.js but I'm not sure about whether its model support is appropriate for my needs. I'm working on a database front-end application which connects to a central server; the main problem here is that the database definition might change (i.e. removing or adding columns).

Editing the code manually to accomodate all changes to the database is something I'd like to avoid at all cost. Therefore, I'd like to know if Ember.js provides a way to generate dynamic models. I've come across [the defineProperty method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594210/ember-js-dynamic-model-properties) but I haven't been able to figure out how it works, neither have I found anything about it in the Ember.js docs. Besides, it seems to be necessary to run it once for each object; is there a way to run it just once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach may be to automate the generation of your client side schema from your database schema.

A similar solution has been demonstrated here (though the implementation is Rails specific) : http://techblog.fundinggates.com/blog/2013/03/automatically-generate-ember-models-from-rails-serializers/

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind but, well, this should do the trick! Many thanks for your help. :)